# apps script - search value from sheet1 in array in sheet2 (google sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm completely new to apps script and java.
I have a tracker where users insert IDs in col1 sheet1. I need to be able to prevent and alert them whenever their input DOESN'T exists in an array in col2 sheet 2.

so far I've got this, but this is not working for me at all.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var so = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); so.activate();
  var vltest = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue()
  var vlary = so.getActiveCell().getValue()
  var r = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow()
  var c = sheet.getActiveRange().getColumn();
  if(vltest!=="" && c==1 && r>1 && sheet == "Sheet1"){ 
    var data = so.getRange("B1:B").getValues().filter(String).flat() 
    if(data.indexOf(vlary)=data.lastIndexOf(vlary)){
      e.range.setValue("")}
if(data.indexOf(vlary)=data.lastIndexOf(vlary)){SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Alert", "Alert", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);}}}

Any ideas?
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all values from compare sheet, loop them through and look for match of the value, that `onEdit()` gives you back. Something like this:

```
    function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet_ID'); //or getActive();
  var so = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  // let's say you get all rows from column 1
  var compareData = so.getRange(1, 1, so.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  for (var d = 0; d < compareData.length; d++) {
    if (compareData[d] === e.value) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Alert", "Alert", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand this logic, but I keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
onEdit`, which I can't seem to resolve.

Comment: If you are running this function within editor, you will always get this error, since `e` comes as `undefined`. You need to trigger this function via editing cell value in the sheet.